# Mysql replication - One Master and two slaves

Tags: mysql, replication

Actually i am facing a issue, one slave is replicating but another slave is not replicating neither it shows any errors.
From master, processlist and show slave hosts shows both slaves and slave status also fine i.e no issues.

Some more details from slave log file, which is not replicating

Slave SQL thread for channel '' initialized, starting replication in log 'mysql-bin.002345' at position 66026713, relay log './mysql-relay-bin.003717' position: 66026926
Slave I/O thread for channel '': connected to master 'repl@xx.xxx.x.xx:3306',replication started in log 'mysql-bin.002345' at position 66026713.

Does these logs mysql-bin.002345 and mysql-relay-bin.003717 should be under slave which is not replicating ? If these logs are not exists under this slave ?

Any suggestions,what i have to check etc.

Any more details required please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please look server_uuid on both slaves. It must be unique on each of slaves. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options.html

Comment: yes,both are unique on respective slaves.From master, show slave hosts:
+-----------+------+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| Server_id | Host | Port | Master_id | Slave_UUID                           |
+-----------+------+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
|         2 |      | 3306 |         1 | cd0d5534-42e8-11ea-9cde-42010a9c000c |->replicating
|        11 |      | 3306 |         1 | 3d54943a-42f1-11ea-9ec1-42010a9c000e |->not replicating
+-----------+------+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+